# No aparece archivo pop.xml en intellij en spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

quería hacerles una consulta, tal vez puedan ayudarme, actualmente estoy haciendo un proyecto de spring boot con intellij, es un curso de Udemy, pero en una parte el profe entra a un archivo llamado pop.xml para agregar unas dependencias, pero ami no me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Había leído en stack overflow en inglés, que en otro ID existe una opción que se llama como avanzada o algo así que el ID debe habilitar para que se muestre, pero con INTELLIJ nose como seria, podrían ayudarme por favor.

Comment: El archivo "pom.xml" aparece cuando utilizas como gestor de dependencias Maven, en tu proyecto estas utilizando Gradle. En ese caso puedes agregar las dependencias en el archivo "build.gradle".

Comment: qué raro según yo era con maven, y eso ya no se puede cambiar ?